# Best way to initialize inline static variable returned by derived class virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, static-variables

Originally I had m_damage as a class member in the base class Projectile, assigned the value in the initializer list in each derived class and had a single getter function in the base class.

But then I realized I dont need every instance of the derived classes holding a copy of m_damage since it was the same value for all instances of each derived class, so I needed to make the value `static` and have each derived class return it in a `virtual` function override.

After researching online and on here I believe `inline static const` variable is the way to go. But is there any benefit to having it as a class member or class constant? or is there another better way to do it? I only want the value accessed via the private virtual function in Projectile.

projectile.h file

```cpp
class Projectile
{
private:
    virtual int getDamage() const = 0;
}
```

rocket .h file

```cpp
class Rocket : public Projectile
{
private:
// inline static const auto ROCKET_DAMAGE = 400;  <---- make it a class member?
    virtual int getDamage() const final override;
}
```

rocket .cpp file

```cpp
// inline static const auto ROCKET_DAMAGE = 400;  <---- make it a class constant?

int Rocket::getDamage() const
{
    return ROCKET_DAMAGE;
}
```

Comment: Better still `static constexpr auto ROCKET_DAMAGE = 400;`?

Comment: i thought `inline static const` was better than `static constexpr` after reading this
"The advantage over constexpr is that your initialization expression doesn't have to be constexpr."
https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2205/7-features-of-c17-that-will-simplify-your-code/inline-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an API design perspective, a constant is an implementation detail. Therefore, you may want to hide this implementation detail – i.e., the constant – behind the definition of a member function in the `.cpp` file as you already have.

In `rocket.hpp`:

```
class Rocket: public Projectile {
private:
    virtual int getDamage() const final override;
};
```

In `rocket.cpp`:

```
static constexpr auto ROCKET_DAMAGE = 400; // not exposed to client

int Rocket::getDamage() const {
    return ROCKET_DAMAGE;
}
```

Note that having the constant `ROCKET_DAMAGE` as a data member as in the example below exposes it to the client:

```
class Rocket: public Projectile {
private:
   inline static const auto ROCKET_DAMAGE = 400;
};
```

The constant may be compiled into the client's code. This would imply that the client code would need to be recompiled every time you change the value of the constant `ROCKET_DAMAGE`.

In contrast, if the constant `ROCKET_DAMAGE` is not exposed to the client through the header file because it is hidden in the `.cpp` file (as in the former case), changing the value of the constant can't possibly require the recompilation of client code.

Comment: yes good point I was leaning more towards not having it in the header file to keep it more hidden

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for static class variables. If it is a constant, and is the same value for all objects of the class, it will just waste memory if it is a data member. I would go ahead and also make it `constexpr` so it is allocated at compile-time, and is available for compile-time computation, should you need it (assuming you have a C++17 enabled compiler}:

```
constexpr static auto ROCKET_DAMAGE = 400;
```

Another way to solve this problem is to not use a static variable, and instead, just return the value directly from the virtual function:

```
int Rocket::getDamage() const
{
    return 400;
}
```

Using a static class variable will make it slightly easier to change the value in the future, if you need to: it is easier to just modify the header file directly as opposed to trawling through the implementation file and finding the correct function definition. This may be a negative, however, if the header file is `#include`-d in multiple files, as it will require recompiling all source files with this header, which means longer compile times.

Comment: I thought magic numbers were bad? :) so in your second suggestion it wouldnt be static and would just return a copy of the value each time?

Comment: You're right, they are bad. Maybe include comments explaining where the variable came from if you choose the second option. A copy of the value will be returned each time, regardless. Its not a big issue in this case, ints are quite cheap.

Comment: thanks for explaining, I think I prefer having a named constant so it's more readable